# Центрировать текст в Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Как максимально без колхозинга отцентровать тест в toolbar?

В идеале через стили или изолированным кодом

```
class DefaultToolbar : Toolbar {

   private fun center() {

   }

}
```

Comment: Разве что вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/3212712

Comment: эх, думал есть возможности без этого. Спасибо

Comment: Если дизайн отличается от стандартного, часто проще выкинуть Toolbar и всё самому с нуля сделать. Кастомизируется он слабо, если дизайнеры очень креативные